# Chess dot com says this was my best move yet I don't have a clue why

Tags: analysis

Whites turn the analyzer suggests that my best move is Nxe5 [image: Nxe5]
I really don't see why as I would just be trading away my knight for a pawn I don't see why this would be a good move

Comment: Can you add a diagram? Without seeing the position, there's no way we can answer this.

Answer (score 13):

Black has an undeveloped queenside, a weak bishop on g7, lots of weaknesses on the light squares and consequently a very weak king position. This suggests potential tactics.

The point of 1. Nxe5 is that it opens the way for the white queen to h5. Together with the white bishop on c4 this should remind you of [Scholar's mate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scholar%27s_mate) or variations of it. Even though you don't end up with immediate mate here, the position with the white queen and bishop entering black's position looks extremely dangerous for black and moves like Nxe5 or potentially moving the knight to other squares should certainly be considered.

Concretely, whichever way black captures the knight on e5 (dxe5 or fxe5), white can regain material by 2. Qh5+ Kd7 (2...Kf8 or 2...Ke7 are answered with 3 Qf7 mate) 3. Qg4+ Kc6 (or Ke8) 4. Qxg7 and end up with a winning position due to the extremely weak black king.

If black does not capture the knight on e5, white still has a decisive advantage due to threats like Nf7 and its dominance on the light squares. Also white is up a pawn, though that is not essential here.

Comment: I'm impressed by the answer, given that no diagram is available in the question. Was it visible before and then removed, or is that a trick of my computer ?

Comment: @Evargalo - I can see the diagram in my computer, and there is no notification that the question was [edit] ...